# Appendix trouble

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, appendices

I am in trouble with my appendix. I include

```
\appendix<br>
\chapter{Appendix Title 1}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
```

but in the TOC does not show the letters. The TOC is just this...

```
Appendix Title 1
.1 Section 1
.2 Section 2
```

without the letters. May someone help? I am using Lyx and I believe I need to include something in the preamble.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please indicate which document class as well as which appendix-related LaTeX packages you use. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `\section*{}`?
For example:

```
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Title 1}
\section*{Section 1}
\section*{Section 2}
```

Comment: Using `\section*` will remove their numbering and will not solve the problem. We have to know the document class used; `article` class, for example, does not have the `\chapter` level...